# With CSS how can I sort by row and column in the table?

Tags: html, css

I want to display the data in the table in column-row form. I'm trying to do this for mobile compatibility. How can I achieve this?
I've looked through a few threads but couldn't find an example with the table.

The table is simply as follows:

```css
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<h2>A basic HTML table</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>
    <th>G</th>
    
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>

</table>



</body>
```

[image: What I want to do:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels a little unsatisfactory, as you need CSS specifically for each column, so you'll need to know the maximum number of columns your table might have, but you can apply a flex order to each column to achieve what you desire. Like this:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
  tbody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  tr {
    display: contents;
  }
  tr>:nth-child(1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  tr>:nth-child(2) {
    order: 2;
  }
  tr>:nth-child(3) {
    order: 3;
  }
  tr>:nth-child(4) {
    order: 4;
  }
  tr>:nth-child(5) {
    order: 5;
  }
  tr>:nth-child(6) {
    order: 6;
  }
  tr>:nth-child(7) {
    order: 7;
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>
    <th>G</th>
    
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I’m having trouble understanding your question. I think you’re asking how to change columns into rows when the device detected as a mobile or screen width less then 768px and the column title are follows into row for each rows. Is that correct?

If that the case then try to change display of columns into a flex.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { table tbody>tr>td {
display: flex !important; }}
```

As for column title first hide it when small screen are detected

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { table tbody>tr>th:nth-of-type(1)~th {
display: none !important; }}
```

Then use javascript to clone column title for each column rows then append inside current column rows. By using loop for each column to get index current column, clone column title by using current index column then append it.

I know it sound very complicated, but this the only way i know how to make it happen.

Comment: Yes I want to do this for mobile. I can write media etc. but I couldn't write css to the table as I said. Also, the code you wrote does not work in the mobile version.

Comment: @ddisdevelpgelis Have you try to clone for column title and append inside td? And why you couldn't write css into table? you should look into my css selector that the table im defined are bit difference from what you are made. So of course it won't changed.

Comment: I can't directly interfere with the code. Because it's on a Wordpress plugin. I can only write CSS or Javascript.
I would appreciate it if you could describe it, please.

Comment: Like i said you need javascript to archive this trought loop for each cell then get index of current cell from current row. You use this index cell to clone column title (th) and append it to current cell.

Comment: Here example without column title for each cell https://jsfiddle.net/ojhre406/

Comment: Just resize the result area you can see how the look on it. But if you want to have a title for each cell you mast use javascript based on step i'm have described